# Cant boot into 15.04 on 3.19.30

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04, encryption

I will try to be as informative as possible of my issue since I don't know what logs might be helpful or where to find them.

I have ubuntu gnome 15.04 on a laptop, a dell inspiron 15 only 4 months old, with full disk encryption set up when I installed. I have been doing manual updates effectively biweekly with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. This has worked out well until about last week when I could not reboot post update, the machine locks up and becomes unresponsive on decryption. In order to boot now, I navigate into advanced settings in grub and choose 3.19.28 Generic rather than 3.19.30 Generic and everything seems to work just fine.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a solution for the kernel 3.19.30, but a workaround. You have a working kernel as you say. Use this kernel in the meantime. Follow the steps below to remove the problematic kernel and avoid an automatic update for some days.

1. Remove the package `linux-generic`

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove linux-generic
   ```
2. Remove the problematic kernel

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic
   sudo apt-get remove linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic
   ```
3. After some days or after the next minor kernel version update,
   reinstall the package `linux-generic` and test the behavior

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic
   ```
4. If the kernel works now, all is fine. If not repeat the steps above.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked as a temporary fix. I'll give it a week or so until I reinstall the package.

Comment: Also a workaround is a answer ;) please accept the answer if it works for you klick the check mark at the left side of the answer.

Comment: I remember having clicked that before to accept it as an answer but I'm not sure why it did not take.